# How to add active class to clicked element and remove it from others?

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript written correctly to add and remove an active class from a clicked element, but when I click an element, the active class isn't removed from the sibling.

**How do I click on one sibling (making it active) and remove the active class from other siblings?**

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navItem.classList.contains('active') ? navItem.classList.remove('active') : navItem.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li.active {
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Sales</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: something like this before changing current element classlist ```document.querySelectorAll('li.active').foreach((li) => li.classList.remove('active'))```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it easier on yourself by putting a classname on the UL tag so you can reference just those items inside it. Then, in your listener, reference the `event` argumet (I called it `e`)

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation li');

navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  navItem.addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelector('.navigation li.active').classList.remove('active');
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li.active {
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class='navigation'>
  <li class="active">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Sales</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)? This way:

```js
menu.onclick = e => {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName != "LI") return;
  menu.querySelector(".active").removeAttribute("class");
  el.setAttribute("class", "active");
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li.active {
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Sales</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why would this be better than iterating over an array of classes?

Comment: @Millhorn If there are 5000 elements to loop through, you would have to loop through each element and add the event listener individually, lagging the client's browser. Also, if you wanted to add another list item programmatically, you wouldn't have to add the event listener again.

Comment: @Spectric I agree with you. Event delegation is correct approach. It will protect from   client browser lagging.

Comment: @Millhorn Take a look at these articles: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation and https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js